# Is there a possibility of creating a visual defrag scrip in python3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, defragmentation

I have been looking for a script that could defrag a HDD but also display what it is defragmenting and what was defragged, through with `os.walk()`. But i've found nothing.

```py
import os
def run():
        filestoscan = 0
        list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
        length = len(list)
        for i in range(0, length):
            select = list[i]
            error = 0
            var = 0
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(select+':/', topdown=True):
                for name in files:
                     var += 0

            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(select+':/', topdown=True):
                for name in files:
                     # do something
run()
```